# How to add android library Volley to a plain maven project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-volley

I would like to try the Volley library on my plain maven project with java 8 or 11. I am however not able to add this dependency properly. It is an android library by google. So I am not using android studio, but just Intellij IDEA with maven.

When I add it as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.volley</groupId>
    <artifactId>volley</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting: `Cannot resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1`

When I include the type pom as instructed here: https://bintray.com/android/android-utils/com.android.volley.volley/1.1.1#

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.volley</groupId>
    <artifactId>volley</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I am not getting errors, but I cannot use the java class from my java source.

I also included the following plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

I know that this library is not available at maven central, so I added jcenter as additional repository:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>bintray-central</id>
    <name>Bintray Central Repository</name>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Any idea if it would be possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have you find something ?

Comment: No I dropped the effort of finding it out. I am still curious though

Comment: What did you use as replace?

Comment: I wanted to add Volley to my project to demonstrate how to configure it, see here: https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl It would have been another http client example next to the other ones. So if you are just looking for an alternative http client, you can view this list and pick any: https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl#tested-clients

Comment: at last I found, volley can be added as external jar

Comment: you can see my answer below.